# beginner java - printing a right triangle backwards

Tags: java, geometry, spacing

last time i was on here, the only question i needed help with in my computer science homework involved making a right triangle on 100 lines, here was the code for that:

```
    public class PrintTriangle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Print a right triangle made up of *
      // starting at 100 and ending with 1
         int i = 100;
         while (i > 0) {
           for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
           System.out.print("*");
           System.out.println();
         i--;
         }
   }
}
```

well now he's asked us to do the inverse. here's the actual question:

> "Write a program that will draw a right triangle of 100 lines in the
>   following  shape: The first line, print 100 '*', the second line, 99
>   '*’... the last line,  only one '*'. Using for loop for this problem.
>   Name the program as  PrintTriangle.java"

```
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

i'm sure it's something simple but everything i've tried up to this point has flopped or only created 1 space at a time. any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated! thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first take a look on both the problems. How would you relate them.

Since the second problem is the reverse of the first, so what you did first in your first code, you need to do that last in this next problem..

So, your loop should actually work backwards where it ended in the below code.

```
int i = 100;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
           System.out.print("*");
```

So, think what you need to do to make this loop work backwards.

**Hint**: -

- Incrementing from 0 to 100 is forward
- Decrementing from 100 to 0 is backwards

  ```
  ****  
   ***  
    **
     *
  ```

Also, in your above pattern you see that you need to first print `spaces` before actually printing your `characters` So, that too you need to consider.

So, here you have to actually print two different characters: -

- Few `Spaces`, followed by,
- Few `*'s`.

**Here's the pattern: -**

- Let's the maximum row is `max` (100 in your case)
- Row (**`i`**) has (**`i`**) number of `spaces` (Row 0 has 0 space, Row 1 has 1 space)
- Then it has (**`n - i`**) number of `stars` (Row 0 has 100 stars, Row 1 has 99 stars)

So, you can see that you actually need `two` loops here.

Analyze what all I said, and come up with some code. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = i; j < 100; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hisham.. Please do not post the working code unless OP tries it himself.. This will not at all help him.

Comment: @RohitJain.. Apologies for this, thought he just wanted the code

Comment: @Hisham.. Its OK. But even if he wants the code, you should not give him. For now its ok. Remember the next time

Comment: yeah i wasn't looking for the actual code, just some helpful hints :) but thank you guys so much i get it now. it was just hard to wrap my head around spaces being their own characters for some reason. brain fart! thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you idea how you can do it.
Understand the pattern.

Just like printed * on previous question you need to print spaces. Then print stars on reverse order.

```
*
**
***

***
 **
  *
```

Comment: No. in the first one spaces need not to be managed. The reversing isn't this straight.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of pyramids (what i call them) first make sure you get the spaces right

```
* * * * *
- * * * *
- - * * *
- - - * * 
- - - - *
```

Now you can see two patterns and now you can program it. Here is psuedocode...

```
FOR I=1 to N
    FOR J = 1 to I-1
        PRINT " "
    ENDFOR
    FOR K = 1 to N-I+1
        PRINT "*"
    ENDFOR
PRINT "\n"
ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int i = 1;
 while (i =< 100) {
   // first put spaces as long as it is necessary
   // it will be i times less than 100
   // for example for the first line (i = 1), 99 space (100-i) and 1 star (i)
   // for the 50. line (i == 50), 50 space (100-i) and 50 stars (i)
   for(int j = 0; j < 100-i; j++)
     System.out.print(" ");

   // then the stars
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
     System.out.print("*");
   System.out.println();
   i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below can help you to find solution.

```
 class ReverseTriangle {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = i; j < 100; j++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintTriangle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       for(int i=10;i>0;i--)
          {
           for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
           System.out.print("*");
           System.out.println();           
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please fix code highlighting and add some description to your code snippet. Read this article from FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printPyramid(int ln){
    for(int j=ln;j>0;j--){
        for(int i=ln;i>0;i--) {
            if (j >= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printReversePyramid(int ln){
    for(int j=0;j<ln;j++){
        for(int i=ln;i>=0;i--) {
            if (j >= i) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printDiamond(int ln){
    for(int j=0;j<2*ln+1;j++){
        for(int i=ln;i>=0;i--) {
            if (j >= i && j < ln+1) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else if(j > ln && (2*ln)-j>=i){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else {
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```